# How to add/mix two bump's

Tags: cycles-render-engine, network

Hello i have a prototype for 3d modeling that have scratchy surface and also a milled logo on surface that is deeper than scratches. So I have two bump files. The question is how in Cycles  separatly adjust  the strait of each bump and then add/mix it together put it in displacement and than bake normal map from all of this.

Comment: There is a *Color Mix* Cycles node with a multitude of blending modes that should cover your use case.

Comment: The mixing of two bump maps is the easy part. Converting that data into a normal map is the tricky part. There is an app called AwesomeBump that can convert it for you. (I haven't tried it myself because I can't find a Mac binary.) Otherwise, you can of course do it all in Blender by baking the combined bump map, and then using that as a displacement map with the Displacement Modifier, and baking a normal map from that. What's confusing is that we can't bake a normal map in tangent space unless we duplicate the object, select also the original, and choose the Selected to Active option.

Comment: [Here's a .blend](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3323/) if you want to see an example. Just click "Bake" on the bottom right. The Image Texture node must remain selected when you do this.